# Trying to replicate this jQuery template using handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I've just came across of handlebars last night and it seems a good way of separating HTML template from your javascript/jQuery code. But I'm having a problem replicating a small simple code in handlebar.

I'm trying to output the item `Price * Quantity`, I'm having a trouble appending the subtotal of the items properly. When I added a new item to my basket it calculate the price of that item and shows it as a new element rather than adding it to the current totalPrice. It's probably because of the `{{#each this }}` in the subTotal as its iterating through the items again.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
         {{#each this}}
         <div class="col-sm-8">{{ Quantity }} {{ Product }}</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right;">{{ Price }}</div>
         {{/each}}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">
      <h4 style="text-align: right;">
         Subtotal:
         {{#each this}}
         <span class="total">{{calculate Price "*" Quantity}}</span>
         {{/each}} 
      </h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my issue -- when it should be 3.98
[image]

My handlebar calculate helper --

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('calculate', function (priceVal, operator, quantity) {
        priceVal = parseFloat(priceVal);
        quantity = parseFloat(quantity);
        return {
            "+": priceVal + quantity,
            "-": priceVal - quantity,
            "*": priceVal * quantity,
            "/": priceVal / quantity,
            "%": priceVal % quantity
        }[operator];
    })
```

jQuery Template that I want to replicate in handlebars

```
 for (product in cartItems) {
        html += '<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">';
        html += '<div class="col-sm-12">';
        html += '<div class="col-sm-8">' + cartItems[product].Quantity + cartItems[product].Product + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right;">' + parseFloat(cartItems[product].Price).toFixed(2) + '</div>';
        html += '</div> </div>';
        var priceInt = parseFloat(cartItems[product].Price);
        var quantityInt = parseFloat(cartItems[product].Quantity);
        totalPrice += priceInt * quantityInt || 0;
        $('.total').text(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer but if someone else have a better idea, please share them

Instead I created a `handlebar.helper` with the `for()` for totalPrice.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('subTotal', function () {
        var totalPrice = 0;
        for (product in cartItems) {
            var priceInt = parseFloat(cartItems[product].Price);
            var quantityInt = parseFloat(cartItems[product].Quantity);
            totalPrice += priceInt * quantityInt || 0;
        }
        if(totalPrice != 0){
            return totalPrice;
        }
    })
```

HTML -- `{{ subTotal }}`